# Linux bash: grep with regex error

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I am trying to detect a NIC is configured or not. (On `Ubuntu` 1604, so the main configuration file will be `/etc/network/interfaces`).

I prepared a regex to search the configure from the interfaces file like below:

```
^[ \t]*(auto|iface|mapping|allow-.*)[ \t]+eth0
```

**This regex works when I put it in grep command directly; but if I put this regex into a variable then used it in grep, then grep will throw error:**

```
grep: Invalid regular expression
```

Can you please help to figure out why put that it does not work that put regex into a variable?

Thanks!

```
root@ci-1-0:/home/lisa# mainfn=/etc/network/interfaces
root@ci-1-0:/home/lisa# nic_name=eth0
root@ci-1-0:/home/lisa# pattern="^[ \t]*(auto|iface|mapping|allow-.*)[ \t]+$nic_name"
root@ci-1-0:/home/lisa# echo $pattern
^[ \t]*(auto|iface|mapping|allow-.*)[ \t]+eth0


root@ci-1-0:/home/lisa# grep -E "^[ \t]*(auto|iface|mapping|allow-.*)[ \t]+eth0" $mainfn
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

root@ci-1-0:/home/lisa# grep -E $pattern $mainfn
grep: Invalid regular expression
```

Comment: Why did you remove the quotes in the second version?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be the cause, but when you are putting it directly into `grep -E`, you have the pattern surrounded by quotes, whereas when using `$pattern` it does not have the quotes. Edit: I just tried it and I don't get a syntax error either way, but try `grep -E "$pattern" $mainfn`

Comment: When the quotes are missing, you are looking for the (invalid) regex `^[` in a file named `\t]*...`.  Keep the quotes.

Comment: The default rule in bash ... until you know better use double quotes around ALL variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my `OS Sierra` terminal, your example gives a slightly different error message:

```
> grep -E $pattern filename
grep: brackets ([ ]) not balanced
```

But if I wrap the pattern in quotes, it works fine:

```
> grep -E "$pattern" filename
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

The issue is that without quotes, the **space** in your pattern is being interpreted as a separator between arguments:

```
grep -E ^[ \t]*(auto|iface|mapping|allow-.*)[ \t]+eth0 filename
          ^ HERE                             ^ (and also here)
```

In other words, it is trying to search for an invalid regex `^[` (with unbalanced brackets, hence my error message), in three files: `"\t]*(auto|iface|mapping|allow-.*)["`, `"\t]+eth0"` (which obviously do not exist), and `"filename"`.

---

As a general rule in `bash`, it's a good idea to wrap *any* use of variables in quotes like this, to avoid such whitespace issues.